# How to change style of View based on binding enum in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to change the style of my `Text` below:

**View**

```
@State var status = Status.offline

Button(action: { self.goOnline() }){
      Text("Offline")
          .statusButtonStyle(color: $status.color)
}.padding().background(Color.black).opacity(0.7).cornerRadius(40.0)

extension Text {
    func statusButtonStyle(color: Color = $status.color) -> Text {
        return self
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

based on an `enum` in my Models file:

**Model**

```
enum Status {
    case offline(color: Color = Color.black)
    case loading(color: Color = Color.gray)
    case online(color: Color = Color.green)
}
```

However the above code poses 2 errors preventing this:

1. My `extension` is showing a `Use of unresolved identifier '$status'`
2. My `enum` is showing a `Use of undeclared type 'Color'`

These are preventing me from executing this binding method for changing the style of the `Text`.

Any idea how I can work around this to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
enum Status {
    case offline(color: Color = .black)
    case loading(color: Color = .gray)
    case online(color: Color = .green)

    var color: Color {
        switch self {
            case .offline(let color):
                return color
            case .loading(let color):
                return color
            case .online(let color):
                return color
        }
    }
}

struct StatusView: View {
    @State var status: Status = .offline()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.goOnline() }){
            Text("Offline")
                .statusButtonStyle(color: status.color)
        }.padding().background(Color.black).opacity(0.7).cornerRadius(40.0)
    }
}

extension Text {
    func statusButtonStyle(color: Color) -> Text {
        return self
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Your extension of `Text` can't recognize `$status` because it is defined in another scope.
2. Your `Status` enum is not recognizing `Color` because you probably didn't import SwiftUI.