# How to create an enum based .textStyle(.title) modifier for Text(...) components in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ipados, swiftui-text

I want to implement a modifier setting for Texts in a similar way as it already exists for Buttons.

Aka:

```swift
Button( ... )
   .buttonStyle(.plain) // <-- .plain and not PlainStyle()
```

**Problem**
Of course I cannot use an opaque which is not really the same. If it would be a `View` I could wrap it in an `AnyView` but for `ViewModifier`s I need another solution.

> Error: Function declares an opaque return type,but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

Maybe it is a bonus idea to have something like a `.textStyle(.title)` modifier but in my eyes, it could reduce my code to write enormously.

**Source**

```swift
struct TitleStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
      ...
    }
}

struct BodyStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
      ...
    }
}


enum TextStyle {
    
    case title
    case body

    // Error: Function declares an opaque return type, 
    // but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types
    var modifier: some ViewModifier {
        switch self
        {
        case .title: return TitleStyle()
        case .body: return BodyStyle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292131/how-to-change-style-of-view-based-on-binding-enum-in-swiftui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works different way. As all this is around generics we need to restrict declarations for known concrete types.

So, having `TitleStyle` and `BodyStyle` declared and concrete, we can specify

```
extension ViewModifier where Self == TitleStyle {
    static var title: TitleStyle { TitleStyle() }
}

extension ViewModifier where Self == BodyStyle {
    static var body: BodyStyle { BodyStyle() }
}
```

and then declare extension to use above like

```
extension View {
    func textStyle<Style: ViewModifier>(_ style: Style) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: style)
    }
}
```

so as a result we can do as demo

```
struct Demo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Text("Demo")
            .textStyle(.title)
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Prepared with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[Test module in GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestTextStyleRestriction.swift)

Comment: What's the difference between `ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: style)` and `self.modifier(style)`?

Comment: IMO, second one internally calls first one.